# Async/await always returns a promise or undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I have been struggling to understand what is wrong with this for a while, but I still cant realize what I am doing wrong.
I am trying to add into the database each item of the user's basket as as an orderItem, with this .map() function (an orderItem in the database corresponds to a product, that is not really relevant for the question but helps if you are struggling to understand the operation) :

```
const orderItems= orderData.map(async product=>{
          const productId=product.id.slice(0,product.id.length-5)

          const targetProduct=await dataSources.ProductAPI.product(productId)

          const name=targetProduct.name
          const quantity=218327

          await dataSources.OrderItemAPI.createOrderItem(orderId,productId,name,quantity,{ttlInSeconds:60*20})
        })
```

Then, I am trying to map each orderItem from the above array `orderItems` to an actual product in the database , like this:

//we find the product corresponding to each orderItem

```
 const productsCorrespondingToOrderItems= orderItems.map(async orderItem=>{
      const trial=await orderItem
      console.log(trial) <--- returns undefined
      // OR just logging orderItem returns a promise
      await dataSources.TransactionAPI.findProductFromOrderItem(orderItem.productId).then(x=>console.log(x))
    })
```

I have checked each item from order items and it looks alright. The problem is that each `orderItem` in `productsCorrespondingToOrderItems` returns eighter a promise, when I am simply logging it , or undefined if I await it. I really dont understand, what am I doing wrong? Thank you so much !

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `map()` callbacks

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks so much for the swift reply ! I dont know how I missed that, will try it out right now !

Comment: What you're attempting to do doesn't make a lot of sense. `Array.map` doesn't work with asynchronous code. `Array.map` is only meant to be used for synchronous code. If you want to do sequential looping using `async/await` you should use `for` or `for ... of` loops. If you want to do parallel asynchronous operations you should create your Promises using `Array.map` then use `Promise.all` to await them.

Comment: @nicholaswmin Thanks a lot ! Didn't know that , will change it with a loop !

Comment: @nicholaswmin - It's **very** common to us `map` with an `async` callback to produce an array of promises that you then wait on (for instance, via `Promise.all` or one of the other promise combinator methods).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes indeed but I already mentioned that in the last part of my comment.

Comment: @nicholaswmin - I hadn't seen the edit. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`async` functions **always** return a promise. You're not returning anything from your `map` callbacks, so since the callbacks are `async` functions, they return promises that are fulfilled with `undefined`.

If you want to wait for all of the promises from your `map` operations to be fulfilled, use `Promise.all` on the result. `Promise.all` returns a promise that will be fulfilled with an array of the fulfillment values of the promises you give it (if they're all fulfilled) or rejected the first time any of them rejects. You wait for that promise either with `await` (in an `async` function) or by calling `.then`/`.catch` on it.

Here's an example that assumes the code where you're doing that `map` is not in an `async` function:

```
// If not in an `async` function
Promise.all(orderData.map(async product => {
    const productId = product.id.slice(0, product.id.length - 5);
    const targetProduct = await dataSources.ProductAPI.product(productId);
    const name = targetProduct.name;
    const quantity = 218327;

    const orderItem await dataSources.OrderItemAPI.createOrderItem(
        orderId,
        productId,
        name,
        quantity,
        { ttlInSeconds: 60 * 20 }
    );
    return await dataSources.TransactionAPI.findProductFromOrderItem(orderItem.productId);
}))
.then(productsCorrespondingToOrderItems => {
    // ...use `productsCorrespondingToOrderItems` here...
})
.catch(error => {
    // ...handle/report error...
});
```

Note that that does the work **in parallel**. If you want to do it in series instead, use an `async` function and a `for-of` loop.

Answer (score 2):

You did not return anything from your map and map does not work for async/await. Do this instead to call the api once at a time (in series). If you want to await multiple api calls at the same time (in parallel), use the answer from TJ Crowder.

```
const orderItems= [];
for (const product of orderData) {
      const productId=product.id.slice(0,product.id.length-5)

      const targetProduct=await dataSources.ProductAPI.product(productId)

      const name=targetProduct.name
      const quantity=218327

      await dataSources.OrderItemAPI.createOrderItem(orderId,productId,name,quantity,{ttlInSeconds:60*20})
    })
    // push something to the orderItems array here!
}
```